getting deadlock with log4j
We are using log4j for logging purposes. We are using log4j 2.x through 1.2 bridge. Due to size of the application, we cannot upgrade to 2.x. Problem we are facing is that at the time of rollover, log4j gets deadlocked and the whole application hangs up. Here are my configuration and thread dump.
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">

<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">
    <appender name="CONSOLE" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.EnhancedPatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{ABSOLUTE} %-5p [%t][%c{1}:%L] %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <appender name="FILE" class="org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <rollingPolicy class="org.apache.log4j.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <param name="FileNamePattern" value="@liferay.home@/logs/liferay@spi.id@.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log" />
        </rollingPolicy>

        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.EnhancedPatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{ABSOLUTE} %-5p [%t][%c{1}:%L] %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <category name="com.browseengine.bobo">
        <priority value="ERROR" />
    </category>

    <root>
        <priority value="INFO" />
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    </root>
</log4j:configuration>

Thread dump:

Found one Java-level deadlock:
=============================
"http-nio-8080-exec-79":
  waiting to lock monitor 0x000001e77592f9f8 (object 0x00000005c2a7e928, a org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender),
  which is held by "http-nio-8080-exec-2"
"http-nio-8080-exec-2":
  waiting to lock monitor 0x000001e76f9b06f8 (object 0x00000005e6beba58, a java.io.OutputStreamWriter),
  which is held by "http-nio-8080-exec-20"
"http-nio-8080-exec-20":
  waiting to lock monitor 0x000001e77592f9f8 (object 0x00000005c2a7e928, a org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender),
  which is held by "http-nio-8080-exec-2"

Java stack information for the threads listed above:
===================================================
"http-nio-8080-exec-79":
    at org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender.rollover(RollingFileAppender.java:224)
    - waiting to lock <0x00000005c2a7e928> (a org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender)
    at org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender.subAppend(RollingFileAppender.java:353)
    at org.apache.log4j.WriterAppender.append(WriterAppender.java:158)
    at org.apache.log4j.AppenderSkeleton.doAppend(AppenderSkeleton.java:112)
    at org.apache.log4j.bridge.AppenderAdapter$Adapter.append(AppenderAdapter.java:59)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.tryCallAppender(AppenderControl.java:161)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.callAppender0(AppenderControl.java:134)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.callAppenderPreventRecursion(AppenderControl.java:125)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.callAppender(AppenderControl.java:89)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.callAppenders(LoggerConfig.java:675)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.processLogEvent(LoggerConfig.java:633)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.log(LoggerConfig.java:616)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.log(LoggerConfig.java:523)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.DefaultReliabilityStrategy.log(DefaultReliabilityStrategy.java:49)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Logger.logMessage(Logger.java:153)
    at org.apache.log4j.Category.forcedLog(Category.java:316)
    at org.apache.log4j.Category.log(Category.java:557)
    at com.liferay.portal.log.Log4jLogImpl.info(Log4jLogImpl.java:83)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.log.LogWrapper.info(LogWrapper.java:123)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.log.SanitizerLogWrapper.info(SanitizerLogWrapper.java:140)
    at com.elixir.tango.helium.events.CustomLoginPostAction.run(CustomLoginPostAction.java:69)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.events.InvokerAction.run(InvokerAction.java:41)
    at com.liferay.portal.events.EventsProcessorImpl.processEvent(EventsProcessorImpl.java:83)
    at com.liferay.portal.events.EventsProcessorImpl.process(EventsProcessorImpl.java:69)
    at com.liferay.portal.ee.license.EventsProcessorImpl.process(Unknown Source)
    at com.liferay.portal.events.EventsProcessorUtil.process(EventsProcessorUtil.java:40)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.MainServlet.loginUser(MainServlet.java:1050)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.MainServlet.service(MainServlet.java:510)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.doFilter(HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.java:126)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:169)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.uploadservletrequest.UploadServletRequestFilter.processFilter(UploadServletRequestFilter.java:93)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:169)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.strip.StripFilter.processFilter(StripFilter.java:361)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:169)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.secure.SecureFilter.processFilter(SecureFilter.java:312)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:169)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.jsoncontenttype.JSONContentTypeFilter.processFilter(JSONContentTypeFilter.java:42)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:185)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:96)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:185)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:96)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:738)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.processFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:57)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:165)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:96)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:165)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:96)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:185)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:96)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter.doFilter(InvokerFilter.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:492)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:165)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:104)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:1025)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at com.elixir.tango.tangofilters.ProcessingValve.invoke(ProcessingValve.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:451)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1201)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:654)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1782)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1741)
    - locked <0x00000005eacac390> (a org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioChannel)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
"http-nio-8080-exec-2":
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.close(StreamEncoder.java:147)
    - waiting to lock <0x00000005e6beba58> (a java.io.OutputStreamWriter)
    at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.close(OutputStreamWriter.java:233)
    at java.io.FilterWriter.close(FilterWriter.java:104)
    at org.apache.log4j.WriterAppender.closeWriter(WriterAppender.java:213)
    at org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender.rollover(RollingFileAppender.java:290)
    - locked <0x00000005c2a7e928> (a org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender)
    at org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender.subAppend(RollingFileAppender.java:353)
    at org.apache.log4j.WriterAppender.append(WriterAppender.java:158)
    at org.apache.log4j.AppenderSkeleton.doAppend(AppenderSkeleton.java:112)
    at org.apache.log4j.bridge.AppenderAdapter$Adapter.append(AppenderAdapter.java:59)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.tryCallAppender(AppenderControl.java:161)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.callAppender0(AppenderControl.java:134)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.callAppenderPreventRecursion(AppenderControl.java:125)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.callAppender(AppenderControl.java:89)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.callAppenders(LoggerConfig.java:675)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.processLogEvent(LoggerConfig.java:633)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.log(LoggerConfig.java:616)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.log(LoggerConfig.java:523)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.DefaultReliabilityStrategy.log(DefaultReliabilityStrategy.java:49)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Logger.logMessage(Logger.java:153)
    at org.apache.log4j.Category.forcedLog(Category.java:316)
    at org.apache.log4j.Category.log(Category.java:557)
    at com.liferay.portal.log.Log4jLogImpl.info(Log4jLogImpl.java:83)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.log.LogWrapper.info(LogWrapper.java:123)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.log.SanitizerLogWrapper.info(SanitizerLogWrapper.java:140)
    at com.elixir.tango.identity.ticket.TangoTicketUtil.getRedisKeyFromTicket(TangoTicketUtil.java:706)
    at com.elixir.tango.identity.helper.filter.TangoServicesAuthFilter.doFilter(TangoServicesAuthFilter.java:136)
    at com.elixir.tango.identity.helper.filter.TangoServicesAuthFilter.doFilter(TangoServicesAuthFilter.java:47)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at com.elixir.tango.store.filter.EntityManagerFilter.doFilter(EntityManagerFilter.java:45)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:492)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:165)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:104)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:1025)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at com.elixir.tango.tangofilters.ProcessingValve.invoke(ProcessingValve.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:451)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1201)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:654)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1782)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1741)
    - locked <0x00000005e9d8f6c0> (a org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioChannel)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
"http-nio-8080-exec-20":
    at org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender.incrementFileLength(RollingFileAppender.java:433)
    - waiting to lock <0x00000005c2a7e928> (a org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender)
    at org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender$CountingOutputStream.write(RollingFileAppender.java:521)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.writeBytes(StreamEncoder.java:221)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlushBuffer(StreamEncoder.java:291)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlush(StreamEncoder.java:295)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flush(StreamEncoder.java:141)
    - locked <0x00000005e6beba58> (a java.io.OutputStreamWriter)
    at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flush(OutputStreamWriter.java:229)
    at org.apache.log4j.helpers.QuietWriter.flush(QuietWriter.java:55)
    at org.apache.log4j.WriterAppender.subAppend(WriterAppender.java:326)
    at org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender.subAppend(RollingFileAppender.java:359)
    at org.apache.log4j.WriterAppender.append(WriterAppender.java:158)
    at org.apache.log4j.AppenderSkeleton.doAppend(AppenderSkeleton.java:112)
    at org.apache.log4j.bridge.AppenderAdapter$Adapter.append(AppenderAdapter.java:59)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.tryCallAppender(AppenderControl.java:161)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.callAppender0(AppenderControl.java:134)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.callAppenderPreventRecursion(AppenderControl.java:125)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.callAppender(AppenderControl.java:89)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.callAppenders(LoggerConfig.java:675)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.processLogEvent(LoggerConfig.java:633)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.log(LoggerConfig.java:616)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.log(LoggerConfig.java:523)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.DefaultReliabilityStrategy.log(DefaultReliabilityStrategy.java:49)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Logger.logMessage(Logger.java:153)
    at org.apache.log4j.Category.forcedLog(Category.java:316)
    at org.apache.log4j.Category.log(Category.java:557)
    at com.liferay.portal.log.Log4jLogImpl.info(Log4jLogImpl.java:83)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.log.LogWrapper.info(LogWrapper.java:123)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.log.SanitizerLogWrapper.info(SanitizerLogWrapper.java:140)
    at com.elixir.tango.identity.ticket.TangoTicketUtil.getRedisKeyFromTicket(TangoTicketUtil.java:706)
    at com.elixir.tango.identity.helper.filter.TangoServicesAuthFilter.doFilter(TangoServicesAuthFilter.java:136)
    at com.elixir.tango.identity.helper.filter.TangoServicesAuthFilter.doFilter(TangoServicesAuthFilter.java:47)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at com.elixir.tango.store.filter.EntityManagerFilter.doFilter(EntityManagerFilter.java:45)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:492)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:165)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:104)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:1025)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at com.elixir.tango.tangofilters.ProcessingValve.invoke(ProcessingValve.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:451)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1201)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:654)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1782)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1741)
    - locked <0x00000005e9d9c9d8> (a org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioChannel)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)

Found 1 deadlock.



Please note that we are using liferay 6.2, java 1.8, log4j-1.2-api-2.17.2.jar and log4j 2.17.2
Update 1:
After updating to latest version of bridge, api and core i.e., log4j-1.2-api-2.23.1.jar, log4j-api-2.23.1, log4j-core-2.23.1.jar, I'm getting below exception:
2024-07-01T11:07:34.858Z localhost-startStop-1 ERROR Unable to create RollingFileAppender, no file name provided.
2024-07-01T11:07:34.936Z localhost-startStop-1 ERROR Could not parse null. java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.log4j.bridge.AppenderWrapper.getName(AppenderWrapper.java:114)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.XmlConfiguration.lambda$parse$6(XmlConfiguration.java:779)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.XmlConfiguration.lambda$forEachElement$8(XmlConfiguration.java:796)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:184)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:175)

With latest version, I'm using below configurations
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">

<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">
    <appender name="CONSOLE" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.EnhancedPatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{ABSOLUTE} %-5p [%t][%c{1}:%L] %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>
    
    <appender name="FILE" class="org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <rollingPolicy class="org.apache.log4j.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <param name="FileNamePattern" value="@liferay.home@/logs/liferay@spi.id@.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log" />
        </rollingPolicy>

        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.EnhancedPatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{ABSOLUTE} %-5p [%t][%c{1}:%L] %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <root>
        <priority value="INFO" />
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    </root>

</log4j:configuration>


Indeed, the RollingFileAppender is not properly synchronized. What is the point of using the logger of a decade latency.

Log4j 1 had many known deadlock problems. This is one of the reasons it was replaced by Log4j 2.
As far as I can tell, you are only using log4j-1.2-api to automatically convert your Log4j 1 configuration file into a Log4j 2 configuration file at runtime. The conversion uses the following algorithm:

if there is a configuration converter in log4j-1.2-api that knows how to convert a Log4j 1 component configuration into the equivalent Log4j 2 component configuration, it is used.
if the component is unknown, Log4j 2 tries to use the native Log4j 1 appender through an adapter.

In your case:

the org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender is replaced by org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.ConsoleAppender,
but org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender (which is not part of Log4j 1, but Apache Extras for Apache Log4j) is used directly.

To solve your problem:

either upgrade Log4j 2 to the newest version (support for the conversion of Apache Extras was added in version 2.18.0, see LOG4J2-3483), which will replace the usage of org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender with the Log4j 2 component org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RollingFileAppender.
or replace the log4j.xml configuration file with the equivalent log4j2.xml configuration file:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Configuration xmlns="https://logging.apache.org/xml/ns"
               xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
               xsi:schemaLocation="https://logging.apache.org/xml/ns
                   https://logging.apache.org/xml/ns/log4j-config-2.xsd">
  <Appenders>
    <Console name="CONSOLE">
      <PatternLayout pattern="%d{ABSOLUTE} %-5p [%t][%c{1}:%L] %m%n"/>
    </Console>
    <RollingFile name="FILE"
                 filePattern="@liferay.home@/logs/liferay@spi.id@.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log">
      <PatternLayout pattern="%d{ABSOLUTE} %-5p [%t][%c{1}:%L] %m%n"/>
      <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy/>
    </RollingFile>
  </Appenders>
  <Loggers>
    <Root level="INFO">
      <AppenderRef ref="CONSOLE"/>
      <AppenderRef ref="FILE"/>
    </Root>
    <Logger name="com.browseengine.bobo" level="ERROR"/>
  </Loggers>
</Configuration>

The second solution is the recommended one, since it does not rely on log4j-1.2-api to convert the configuration file.
Remark: You can check our updated migration page.
Given that almost nobody uses Log4j 1 directly in their code since 20 years (the time JCL and SLF4J were released), chances are you can already remove log4j-1.2-api from your dependencies.

Please see update 1. Any help ?

If I use configurations you provided, it says:
2024-07-01T11:20:28.865Z localhost-startStop-1 ERROR DOM element is - not a log4j:configuration element.

Did you rename the file from log4j.xml to log4j2.xml?

Thanks a lot Karwasz. I tried changing the xml name to log4j2.xml but it didn't work. later adding file param worked. Although I need to figure out how I can use variables in the value of file param. But logs are now generating. One thing I'm not sure about that you can help me with is that if I use AsyncAppender would that help me in this deadlock issue ?

As long as you are using o.a.l.rolling.RollingFileAppender instead of o.a.l.l.c.appender.rolling.RollingFileAppender you are bound to experience Log4j 1 bugs. I would investigate with -Dlog4j2.debug to see why the log4j2.xml file is not read. Since you certainly have apache-log4j-extras on your classpath, you probably also have both log4j:log4j and log4j-1.2-api, which will cause hard to debug classpath problems.

Thanks a lot for all the help. We went for upgrading the jars (including the bridge) to the latest version i.e., 2.23.1. But after that we started facing a different issue i.e., current log file was getting created but at the time of rollover it was successfully renamed to rolled over file but after rollover new current log was not getting created and throwing access denied exception. As mentioned above, we are using kubernetes env with windows server core container with SMB/FSx storage. I think this might be culprit here.

Please report an issue with the details of the error.

Problem lies in method
public synchronized void incrementFileLength(int increment) {
    this.fileLength += (long)increment;
}

of RollingFileAppender.
It shouldn't be synchronized on this.
Unfortunately bug isn't fixed yet.
Fortunately it reproduces in rare circumstances.

Another good reason to migrate away from log4j 1.x as soon as possible.
